# PHP file is not reading SQLite3 database

Tags: php, sqlite

The file update_database.php, processes the data a user fills in on a separate html page and saves it on an SQlite3 database. My program `calendar2.php` should read the data from the SQlite3 database and display the events in the correct time slots and for the correct person on the calendar. For each slot my code calls a function called `get_events($person, $timestamp)`. This function is supposed to return a string containing all events that should be displayed in the time slot in question but it is not working. Any ideas why?

This is my `get_events()` function

```
function get_events($person, $timestamp){
    $database = "dbyourusername.db";
    try
    {
         $db = new SQLite3($database);
    }
    catch (Exception $exception)
    {
        echo '<p>There was an error connecting to the database!</p>';
        if ($db)
        {
            echo $exception->getMessage();
        }
    }
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE person=:person AND time=:time");
    $stmt->bindValue(':person', $person);
    $stmt->bindValue(':time', $timestamp);
    $result = $stmt -> execute();
    return $result->fetchArray();
}
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Please read [ask].

Comment: I mean that my calendar2.php is not reading or displaying the data that is saved in the sqlite3 database.

Comment: Okay, but is your exception getting thrown? Or are you getting some other error? Or is the query working, but you're not getting the results you expect?

Comment: You should return from the function if the error is caught. Otherwise you'll try to perform the query even though you couldn't open the database.

Comment: Try using the full pathname to `dbyourusername.db`.